# How to access a hash inside of an array by key

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at this code I am not able to get the value of 'start' in the hash.

```
 w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
    });
```

I thought I could do:

```
w[l].start
```

or

```
w[l]['start']
```

But I get undefined errors.

w is passed in as a parameter, and it is a window object.

Comment: the name of the properly is `gtm.start`

Comment: also `w[l]` is an array

Comment: what about `w[l].gtm.start`

Answer (score 1):

Working JsBin: https://jsbin.com/zilado/1/edit?js,console

So lets say you start with an empty array at `w[1]`, w itself is also an array.

You then push an `Object` to that array so `w[1]` is an array with an `Object` in it, that object has what your looking for, and you can access it like so:

```
var w = [];
w[1] = [];


w[1].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime()});

console.log(w[1][0]['gtm.start'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`w[l]` is an array `w[l] = w[l] || [];`

Then you push an object to that array `w[l].push({ ...`

So you can access that object property with `w[l][0]['gtm.start']` (assuming that the array is empty when you pushed the object)